# AWS EC2: How can I have a "Scheduled Action" in an "Auto Scaling Group" stick?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I'm trying to set up an "Auto Scaling Group" on AWS EC2. I added a `Scheduled Action` that sets start and end time and `recurring` daily. When the start time is reached, the system changes accordingly. It seems at this point that the scheduled action is consumed. The end time is happily ignored (not executed/ no scale down). Also: since there is no "schedule action" anymore, I doubt that it will be executed the following day.

How can I make an action to an "Auto Scaling Group" stick, remembering its start time, end time and recurrence?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using cron expression in your scheduled scaling.

https://mohankamaraj.wordpress.com/2016/08/10/auto-scaling-scheduled-scaling-using-cron-expression/

Comment: Thanks. I tried that too. But I guess the behaviour whether using cron or `daily` should be similar. In my case the action gets consumed after execution and is never heard of again.

Answer (score 0):

`end_time` doesn't mean the scheduler will return the number of instances to its base (because it won't know what the "base" is). `end_time` only means that the scheduler you set to won't start again for the next occurrence (e.q. if you set only for particular dates 1-5 Jan for new year campaign).

To set the scheduler to return to its "base number", set another scheduler. So there would be 2 schedulers:

- scheduler A to increase number of instance e.q. start at 1 Jan 00:00 end at 1 Jan 01:00 (let say it's one time only and not recurring)
- scheduler B to decrease number of instance e.q. start at 6 Jan 00:00 end at 6 Jan 01:00 (let say it's one time only and not recurring)

Btw, it's also possible to set cron job (e.q. start for 09:00 every day from 1-5 Jan). See them more at https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/schedule_time.html